# Matlab error - Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values

Tags: matlab, operands

```
whitePixels=ext_rows((150<ext_rows) && (ext_rows<200));
numberWhitePixels=numel(whitePixels);
```

> error : Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

How can I solve this error? Could you please write down the correct code here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `ext_rows` is a numerical array, you want to use `&` and `|` instead of `&&` and `||`.

The latter only work with with single (scalar) logical values, and their purpose is to skip unecessary logical checks in your code. See the [help page for short circuits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html#bt_0nai-1) for more information. If your array is very large, consider using [anyExceed](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27857-anyexceed).

To see why your example needs the first set of operators, create a variable to indicate if `ext_rows` is greater than 150. We then check if it is both logical and a scalar.

```
# note: I would consider rewriting it as ext_rows > 150 for readability
over150 = 150 < ext_rows; 
islogical(over150) # true
isscalar(over150) # false
```

Notice that the second call is false because `over150` is an array of logicals that indicate if each element is greater than 150. The same will be true if `ext_rows` is less than 200.

```
under200 = ext_rows < 200;
islogical(under200) # passes
isscalar(under200) # fails
```

Using the above, which is essentially what you had originally, but now with an `&` to get the indices for all elements within the range, gives us the following:

```
idxWhitePixels = over150 & under200;
whitePixels = ext_rows(idxWhitePixels);
```